# One command to count all sessions lasting more than an hour

Tags: linux, shell

I want to count all sessions longer than an hour, right now my solution looks like this:

```
last | rev  | cut -d" " -f1 | rev | tr -d "()" | egrep ":[0-9]{2}" | awk -F'[+:]' '{if(NF==3 || (NF==2 && $1 > 0)) print $0}' | wc -l
```

But I don't think it is really an elegant solution. Is there an other way to do this, using the last program itself?

Comment: My `last` doesn't have any options to filter by session length, but you could do everything in a single awk statement.

Comment: I can't see what `rev | cut -d " " -f1 | rev` is adding. Why not just `cut -d " " -f1`? But yes, really all in one `awk` should be very easy. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one?

```
last | awk 'BEGIN{c=0}$NF~/[0-9]/{a=gensub(/\(([^:]+):.*/,"\\1",1,$NF);if(a!="00"){c++}}END{print c}'
```

Set a counter (c) to zero, for any line where the last field has a digit in it, split the last field at the colon, compare the left side against 00 (less than an hour), if they don't match, increment the counter; when all lines are processed, print the counter.